# ASP.NET MVC Calendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, calendar

I am looking calendar for asp.net mvc like a calendar control in asp.net webforms. Not event calendar, not date picker - simple calendar (jquery, helper -  doesn't matter).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try [this](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

> FullCalendar is a jQuery plugin that
>   provides a full-sized, drag & drop
>   calendar like the one below. It uses
>   AJAX to fetch events on-the-fly for
>   each month and is easily configured to
>   use your own feed format (an extension
>   is provided for Google Calendar). It
>   is visually customizable and exposes
>   hooks for user-triggered events (like
>   clicking or dragging an event). It is
>   open source and dual licensed under
>   the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.

[Its](http://eisabainyo.net/demo/jquery.calendar-widget.php) good simple calender
[This](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) DatePicker can be inline

Comment: It's an event calendar. But I need simple calendar like a calendar control in asp.net webforms.

Comment: Like this(http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_calendar) I updated answer

Comment: Yeah, I need a calendar like this   for asp.net mvc.

Comment: @shaahin - I don't need a date picker! I need a calendar.

Comment: Well, check another simple calender I added to answer.

Answer (score 7):

You may look at [Daypilot](http://www.daypilot.org/demo/)