# ASP.NET MVC Datepicker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc and i need calendar or datepicker control but my customer is using windows ce. I saw this topic: [ASP.NET MVC Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932869/asp-net-mvc-calendar) and i used jquery ui datepicker but it's so slow for windows ce's browser (internet explorer mobile).
i need simple datepicker control for asp.net mvc like asp.net webforms calendar control.
such as: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_calendar

Comment: The only solution is to build your own, in a lite verion for the CE browser, if the question was, What can i do to implement a fast calendar for CE browsers.

Comment: Did you take a look at Jquery mobile?
If this is not something you like you have to create your own or find some other plugin that will work on CE device..

Comment: @Zabavsky: sorry for my poor english skills, questions or request is "i need simple datepicker control for asp.net mvc like asp.net webforms calendar control. such as: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?"

Comment: @Freeman: i haven't got much time for implement my own control

Comment: @JordyvanEijk: i'm using jquery ui maybe i should use jquery mobile. i will try jquery mobile. thanks.

Comment: @Baris I understand you need datepicker, but this is not a datepicker factory, it's a community that helps clear some problems in development.

Comment: @Freeman: thanks, i'm sorry. i know, here is a community. i only said; "i haven't god much time for implement my own control". i don't said; "hey! you implement datepicker for me". my english is bad sorry. i need quick solution for it because i haven't much time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at [JQuery mobile](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/textinputs) as @Jordy van Eijk suggested. (The input is called "Date")