# How to use a simple calender in MVC 4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor-2

I am very new on MVC. How can I use a calender? Here is my div

```
   <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CommunicationTime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommunicationTime)
    </div>
```

But it shows only a text box. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932869/asp-net-mvc-calendar or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956312/calender-control-in-c-sharp-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: I just want to select a day and set date to a textbox

Comment: There's a suggestion for that in an answer for the second question.  It links to a jQuery plugin called [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: @cagin HTML5 Type="Date" can do that just try it, I'm Encouraging you to use annotations

Comment: Here I find the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423888/mvc-4-razor-adding-input-type-date

Answer (score 1):

try to add Data annotations DateType(DateType.Date) within your model
here is a sample :

> [Display(Name = "Date of Birthday")]
>
> [DataType(DataType.Date)]
>
> public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

this Should work in Chrome , Firefox , Safari or any  browser Supports HTML5
that's because the produced html tags will contain **type="Date"** in date field